# What to use mipmap or drawable

Tags: android, manifest, drawable

I am new android user and using Android Studio 1.3. I want to create simple splash screen, for that,i create different drawable folders where i store splash screen background images. I copy all ic_launcher from respective mipmap folders and paste them in respective drawable folders. and change icon path in manifest also.as,

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

to,

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

but this is giving me error that,

```
Error:(14, 24) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').
```

My question is,

1. Does we always need to store app icons in mipmap folders only? why?
2. When to use mipmap and drawable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using mipmaps for your launcher icon is described as best practice by the Android team. The advantage you get is that you can keep resources in the mipmap folders for all device densities and then strip out other resources from the drawable folders that are not relevant to the specific users device density.

For example a user has a device that is classified as xxhdpi. The drawable resources in your apk for all other densities, such as xxxhdpi, are not required and can be stripped out.

[reference](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/goodbye-launcher-drawables-hello-mipmaps/)

Comment: Thank you, its really helpful

Comment: @User_1191 You are welcome. Can you accept the answer so other user can know this answer can be used as reference.

Answer (score 1):

The mipmap folders are for placing your app/launcher icons (which are shown on the homescreen) in only.
Any other drawable assets you use should be placed in the relevant drawable folders as before.

According to this Google blogpost and Android Dev's Recommended:

> It’s best practice to place your app icons in mipmap- folders (not the drawable- folders) because they are used at resolutions different from the device’s current density.

Comment: What is "this Google blogpost" and where does the quote come from? Please provide a reference.